# allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost not working ios 10 phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I added in the AppDelegate

```
@implementation NSURLRequest (DataController)
+ (BOOL) allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *) host{
return YES;
}
@end
```

In the plist I have included:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I'm making the requests to a non-secure api
[image: I'm making the requests to a non-secure api]

Is someone also having the same problem?

Comment: Do you find any solution.. I am having same issue !!!

Comment: You have two choices:

1. Work with a secure API.
2. Make requests with a native library and not directly with javascript